# Error creating read replica on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to create a read replica for Google Cloud SQL MysQL Second generation. When I click 'Create', I'm getting two notifications. The first one is `Instance is being created`, and immediately after I'm getting this error.

> Operation failed: Invalid parameter: Replica should have the same network as the master: projects/myproject-production-1/global/networks/compute-network-aaa8ff1ec6b52092 vs https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/myproject-production-1/global/networks/compute-network-aaa8ff1ec6b52092.

As you can notice, it is the same network name; the difference is that it is prepended with `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/`. Furthermore, I am not able to change the network in the read replica configuration anyway, it is grayed out and defaults to the master instance's network.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the Google Cloud SQL as the backend network for replica creation is somehow managed already.

You can re-attempt to create the read replica but if the error persists, it will be better to report the issue here:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=1162714

I was able to create one on my side and this can be an isolated or transient error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an issue with my Cloud SQL instance. Restarting it did the trick.